# Hide/show div acting on keyup filter input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that works with a filter to display the current view of tr's in a table. Pretty simple...when you type in the filter, the table updates based on that query and returns the corresponding amount: Displaying 25 results for Search: ________ (the number changes). I then have a div included at the end of that statement that just reflects the text put into the filter: Displaying 25 results for Search: _______ **and Filter "blah"**. I am looking to be able to hide that div when the filter text is deleted from the filter...the filter is deactivated. As of now, it will clear the actual text **blah** but leave the rest of the div **and Filter " "**.

Why is this happening? It should be activated/deactivated by the "keyup" of the filter, right? I have tried creating a separate function and adding an if else statement...no dice. I've also tried jQuery's hide() and show() methods as is used for the `$('tbody.searchable').hide();` without luck. I'd like it to remain within the same "keyup" function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    (function($) {
        $('#filter').keyup(function() {
            var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
            $('tbody.searchable').hide();
            $('tbody.searchable').filter(function() {
                return rex.test($(this).text());
            }).show();

            var x = $('tbody.searchable:visible').length; 
            document.getElementById("filterUpdate").innerHTML = x;

          //NEED TO HIDE THIS AFTER TEXT IN THE FILTER IS BACKSPACED (FILTER IS DEACTIVATED)
            $('#filterText').html('and Filter = "' + $('#filter').val()+'"');

        })

        $('tbody').on("click", function() {
            if($(this).data('href') !== undefined){
                document.location = $(this).data('href');
            }
        });
    }(jQuery));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check whether the input value is empty or not:

```
$('#filterText').html($(this).val() ? 'and Filter = "' + $('#filter').val()+'"' : '');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hps4yczg/)

Comment: Aha! Too easy. Thanks a bunch!